# ObjectMapper breaking AWS Lambda via API Gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

There is an API Gateway calling a lambda function using the lambda proxy.

The below works fine body is logged and body is sent back:

```
package com.dapper.cloud.function;

import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent;

public class GrantJwt implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent>{ 
    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(Map<String, Object> input, Context context){

        System.out.println(input.get("body").toString());

        return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().withStatusCode(200).withBody(input.get("body").toString());
    }
}
```

When I update it to use the `ObjectMapper` like so:

```
package com.dapper.cloud.function;

import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class GrantJwt implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent>{ 
    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(Map<String, Object> input, Context context){
        ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(input.get("body").toString());

        return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().withStatusCode(200).withBody(input.get("body").toString());
    }
}
```

The logs do not show the body and the response is:

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Can I use Jackson in AWS Lambda?

Parent POM

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Child Build

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It looks like you're not actually using your objectmapper, you're just instantiating it?

Comment: @SimonB At this moment that is correct

Comment: Maybe try autowiring it instead.

Comment: @SimonB do you mean just using the input and output streams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as foolish but if this helps anyone I am very happy.

ObjectMapper is not the issue. I did a deployment with travis-ci a couple times and apparently when that happens if a memory_size and timeout is not set a default 128 mb and 3 second is used. This differs from the defaults of a new lambda which is 512 mb and 15 seconds.

I opened a request to change this on travis forum.